# Refusing connection while trying to connect localhost

Tags: java, connection, p2p

I was trying to develop a p2p file transfer application on java and as for the beginning I decided to run some transfer tests using localhost, as for the server, between local drives by some codes I found on the internet marked as working. The problem is for every port number I tried so far(+20) I got a "connection refused" error. I've installed microsoft loopback adapter as precaution, yet couldn't find any way to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

just in case, I'm writing some code part related to socket in the client class.

> // localhost for testing
>           Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",15123);
>           System.out.println("Connecting...");

and here is the error message

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Client.main(Client.java:12)
```

`line 12 is Socket sock = servsock.accept();`

Comment: write "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" and then try.I guess you have some firewall settings which is not allowing you to connect

Comment: localhost did not solve it as well, I had a permission dialogue requesting privilege, after that it worked for once but it doesn't work now although I didn't performed any changes, which is awkward

Comment: Do a little read up at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: OK then try to change the port. Go and write netstat -a -o -n in cmd(on windows) to see the ports available to you

Comment: found a free port and it solved the problem thanks a lot

Comment: :) sounds good.As you are new here so I should tell you that Now you need to accept my answer.You can accept it by click on the tick present beside my answer.It will turn gren and make me happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often , I saw that this exception comes when there is no service available to listen.Try to use another(free) port and make it sure that your server is running.You can find free port by writing `netstat -a -o -n` in cmd(on windows)

Comment: yeah seems the port I tried was occupied, finding a free port solved the problem

Comment: Goodluck for the coding in future :)